# Mongoose: Populate an array of related values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm fairly new to Mongo and Mongoose, so if this question is rather silly then feel free to point me in the right direction.

I have a API with models for users and stories that they published. When I display the users, I want the stories to show as well.

The relation is drawn rather simply:

```js
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: String,
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  birthday: {
    type: Date,
  },
  bio: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  country: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Country',
  },
  stories: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Story',
  }]
})
```

With a stories scheme declared as such:

```
const storySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    max: 255,
  },
  url: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  length: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  createdAt: Date,
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  language: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Country'
  },
  type: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'StoryType'
  },
  genre: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Genre'
  },
})
```

I print the values using the simple `find` method (the action for now is only meant to show all of them.

```
app.get('/list-users', async (req, res) => {
    const users = await User.find().populate('country').populate('stories').exec();

    res.json(users);
});
```

Unfortunately, although the results show all the values properly, the stories array does not get populated at all.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6127ce5b0576979256fd3e08",
        "username": "test",
        "password": "123",
        "firstName": "tst",
        "lastName": "tst",
        "birthday": "1995-11-02T00:00:00.000Z",
        "country": {
            "_id": "6127c020f95eb5abf72f713a",
            "name": "Poland",
            "languange": "Polish",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "stories": [],
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

[The docs have a clear indicator that such schemas will return an empty array](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#doc-not-found), and I am aware I could just run a find by User and populate with that but I'm wondering what is the cleanest solution to apply in a situation like this.

Any help would be of great value.

Comment: What does your stories schema look like? What you could actually do is access the nested values via `.` notation for the path (in stories), and select the items you want included from the nested array (if it was an array of objects for example).

Comment: @Bogie Hi! Added the schema to the question. I'm not sure what do you mean by the nested values. Could you please provide an example? Like said, fairly green :)

Comment: Sure, by nested, I mean values that are deeper in the Schema list (i.e. values nested within the stories schema like "name" or "url" in your example). First try `.populate('stories', 'username birthday')` for example. The first field is what to populate (the array of stories) and the second field would be the fields from nested objects in that array (story objects, which would contain 'username' and 'birthday' for example, the two fields we are requesting to be included with that array. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: @Bogie I've tried to use the given code but to no avail. I've also tried to use fields from the story schema, but the effect was still the same

Comment: By fields, do you mean `.populate('stories.username')`? Because that should also theoretically populate it.  Might seem obvious, but have you also double checked the arrays field are indeed not empty? Besides that, you can also try running the callback without the async function in case the exec() might be running some problematic validation. Try to remove async await and run `User.find().populate('country').populate('stories', 'username birthday').then((user) => res.json(user)` to see if it's related to that.